# Unable to Copy the Media/Images from one project to the another on build in c# in VS 2022 in Wpf (using WindowsApp SDK)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, csproj, windows-app-sdk

I have these two csproj

One the main project

LIT

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
        <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
        <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
        <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp" Version="5.5.13.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="itextsharp.xmlworker" Version="5.5.13.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230822000" />
        <PackageReference Include="Nuctech.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity" Version="8.1.97" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.Wpf" Version="8.1.97" />
        <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="SuperJMN.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.0.2" />

    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\LIT.Core\LIT.Core.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\LITModels\LITModels.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Modules\LIT.Modules.TabControl\LIT.Modules.TabControl.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\SQLDataAccessLayer\SQLDataAccessLayer.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the project where the images are stored
LIT.Core

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
        <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
        <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
        <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Media\Images\box-green.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\check.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\checked.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\delete.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\delimages.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\deticon.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\edit.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\folder-search2.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\folder.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\house.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\image_2023_06_30T13_35_12_642Z.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\LIV_interary_logo.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\LIV_logo.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\LIV_logo_3.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\login_bg.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\next-arrow.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\next_move.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\next_shift.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\null.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\paperClip.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\plus.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\prev-arrow.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\save.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\sell.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\sendEmail.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\tickimg.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\unchecked.png" />
        <None Remove="Media\Images\warning.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Common" Version="8.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics" Version="8.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.HighPerformance" Version="8.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230822000" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.1.39" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity" Version="8.1.97" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.Wpf" Version="8.1.97" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\box-green.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\check.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\checked.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\delete.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\delimages.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\deticon.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\edit.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\folder-search2.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\folder.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\house.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\image_2023_06_30T13_35_12_642Z.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\LIV_interary_logo.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\LIV_logo.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\LIV_logo_3.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\login_bg.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\next-arrow.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\next_move.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\next_shift.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\null.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\paperClip.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\plus.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\prev-arrow.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\save.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\sell.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\sendEmail.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\tickimg.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\unchecked.png" />
        <Resource Include="Media\Images\warning.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

The error I am getting is this

Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Users\MANAV\Downloads\WindowsSDK_NewPrismUpgrade_MajorArchImprove\LIT\LIT.Core\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\LIT.Core\Media\Images\box-green.png" because it was not found.  LIT C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    5167

Although I have reference of LIT.Core in LIT
everything is correctly referred but couldn't understand why it is not picking up the resource, although the resource is usable in the xaml.

Comment: Error says "because it was not found".  The code is looking for "net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0",  I would first try a clean build and see if that solves issue.  You either do not have the library  loaded or wrong version of library.  You are running the debug version so I would check the bin folder and see if files are in the release instead of the build folder.  Also cases like this you are running the X64 arm version and the build folder may have different build options.  You may need to change the build properties of the project.  Check the project bin folder to see what files exist.

Comment: Cases like this the child project may of failed.  Try compiling child project by itself.

Comment: @jdweng nope it is not in the Release, I did all this, still there

Comment: Search machine for file box-green.png

Comment: @jdweng
`LIT.Core/
│
├── LIT.Core.csproj
├── Media/
│   └── Images/
│       ├── box-green.png
│       ├── check.jpg
│       └── other images...`

It is in the correct directory, but on build the other project is not taking the reference, even though I have give it

Comment: @jdweng The thing is it works fine, but the issue is when I install Windows App SDK as nuget, it causes the trouble

Comment: Since the file is in the folder C:\Users\MANAV only the users and an admin has access to the file.  If file is needed by other users it should be in a shared drive where everybody has access.